# Building a vertical menu using md-menu and material icons

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Im trying to use `md-menu` to create a vertical menu and use the material icons.

But all I get is a horizontal menu, and the icons are not aligned and will not work when I put them into `<md-icon md-svg-icon="hotel" md-menu-align-target></md-icon>`

Here is my code.

```
<md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target" class="">

    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdMenu.open()">
        <img src="../img/Menu.png" alt="Menu">
    </md-button>

    <md-menu-content width="2">
    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ui-sref="book"> <span md-menu-align-target><i class="material-icons">hotel</i> New Booking</span></md-button>
        <md-button ui-sref="book"> <span md-menu-align-target><i class="material-icons">hotel</i> New Booking</span></md-button>
        <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
        <md-button ui-sref="book"> <span md-menu-align-target><i class="material-icons">hotel</i> New Booking</span></md-button>
        <md-button ui-sref="book"> <span md-menu-align-target><i class="material-icons">hotel</i> New Booking</span></md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>

</md-menu>
```

On top is what I want, and below is what my current code looks like:

[image]

**FIRST PROBLEM** Getting the menu to be vertical and positioning it under my arrow button.

**SECOND PROBLEM** Getting the icons to appear like they do in the angular examples that I tried.

I tried making the buttons like this:

```
<md-button ui-sref="book">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="hotel" md-menu-align-target></md-icon>
    Booking
</md-button>
```

But then I get no icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right html structure, md-menu-item should contains each menu item, should be:

```
  <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ui-sref="book"> <span md-menu-align-target><i class="material-icons">hotel</i> New Booking</span></md-button>
 </md-menu-item>
 <md-menu-item>
      <md-button ui-sref="book"> <span md-menu-align-target><i class="material-icons">hotel</i> New Booking</span></md-button>
 </md-menu-item>
       ...
```

Comment: Argh!!! you are right Fetra!! - I didnt see that one :-D - any idea how to get `md-svg-icon="hotel"` to show icons?

Comment: Do you load the material icons (css) described here? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon

Comment: I tried to use this one:  `$ npm install material-design-icons` and it finished installing everything (was a LOT, took 10 minutes almost).  But still their examples are not working.

Comment: You just need to put <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> in index.html

Comment: If I do that, then whats the point of installing them all?.  Anyway I solved it by doing `<md-icon class="material-icons">hotel</md-icon>` so apparently the install actually put in the classes.

Comment: It's like all fonts (fontawesome, ionicons,...) you can install and load them locally, or use external file.